# JDA - Add Role to User if a certain Role is added

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to code a discord bot that adds a new role to a user if a role is added to him. I'm stuck on the role-adding part.

Here's my code. I hope someone can help:

```java
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.member.GuildMemberRoleAddEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class TeamAutorole extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberRoleAdd(GuildMemberRoleAddEvent e) {
        if(e.getRoles().toString().contains("\uD83D\uDC6ESupporter")) {


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you want to check, if the list of roles of the member contains the role you want and then add another role depending on that.

```java
//gets role with name "\uD83D\uDC6ESupporter"
Role supporter = e.getGuild().getRolesByName("\uD83D\uDC6ESupporter", true).get(0);

//gets role with name "Dummy"
Role dummy = e.getGuild().getRolesByName("Dummy", true).get(0);

//check if the list of roles of the user contains the role supporter
if (e.getMember().getRoles().contains(supporter)) {
    
    //adds role dummy to member
    e.getGuild().addRoleToMember(e.getMember(), dummy).queue();

}
```